# ERROR [22P02] ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "";

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, sql-update

Never seen such error:

> ERROR [22P02] ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: ""; Error while executing the query

Creating table:

```
    Public Function PrimkCreate(ByVal myPrimkTable As String, ByVal nCon As OdbcConnection) As Integer
    Dim ans As Integer
    Dim cCommand As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + myPrimkTable + "(" & _
            "prm_id int NOT NULL, " & _
            "pkni text, " & _
            "pdatum text, " & _
            "pdatumnaplate text, " & _
            "pdanaodgode int, " & _
            "puldok text, " & _
            "puldokbroj text, " & _
            "pdatumk text, " & _
            "pvrijemek text, " & _
            "pdobid int, " & _
            "pdoboib text, " & _
            "pnabc double precision, " & _
            "purab double precision, " & _
            "ppdv double precision, " & _
            "ppnak double precision, " & _
            "pprodc double precision, " & _
            "pvrstaprimke int, " & _
            "pzapisniktekst text, " & _
            "prez text, " & _
            "CONSTRAINT " & myPrimkTable & "_pkey PRIMARY KEY(prm_id))", nCon)

    ans = cCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cCommand.Dispose()
    Return ans
End Function
```

Update code:

```
    Public Function update_LPrimk(ByRef primk As Integer, ByVal mCon As OdbcConnection) As Integer

    Dim retval As Integer
    Dim uCmd As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand("UPDATE " & myPrimkTable & " SET " & _
                "prm_id=" & primk & ", " & _
                "pkni='" & prm.pKni & "', " & _
                "pdatum='" & prm.pDatum & "', " & _
                "pdatumnaplate='" & prm.pDatumNaplate & "', " & _
                "pdanaodgode=" & prm.pDanaodgode & ", " & _
                "puldok='" & prm.pUlDok & "', " & _
                "puldokbroj='" & prm.pUlDokBroj & "', " & _
                "pdatumk='" & prm.pDatumk & "', " & _
                "pvrijemek='" & prm.pVrijemek & "', " & _
                "pdobid='" & prm.pDobID & "', " & _
                "pdoboib='" & prm.pDobOib & "', " & _
                "pnabc='" & Replace(prm.pNabc.ToString, ",", ".") & "', " & _
                "purab='" & Replace(prm.pURab.ToString, ",", ".") & "', " & _
                "ppdv='" & Replace(prm.pPdv.ToString, ",", ".") & "', " & _
                "ppnak='" & Replace(prm.pPnak.ToString, ",", ".") & "', " & _
                "pprodc='" & Replace(prm.pProdc.ToString, ",", ".") & "', " & _
                "pvrstaprimke=" & prm.pVrstaPrimke & ", " & _
                "pzapisniktekst='" & prm.pZapisnikTekst & "', " & _
                "prez='" & prm.pRez & "' " & _
                "WHERE prm_id=" + primk.ToString, mCon)

    retval = uCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    uCmd.Dispose()
    Return retval
End Function
```

Query looks exactly like this:

```
UPDATE primke SET prm_id=1, pkni='U', pdatum='07.01.2013', pdatumnaplate='10.01.2013',
pdanaodgode=3, puldok='ghkzug gugug', puldokbroj='jkhk', pdatumk='', pvrijemek='', 
pdobid='', pdoboib='', pnabc='0', purab='0', ppdv='0', ppnak='0', pprodc='0', 
pvrstaprimke=0, pzapisniktekst='', prez='' WHERE prm_id=1
```

I have many tables where I run similar commands but have never seen such an error.
What might be the problem?

Comment: `'0'` is not a valid number, it's character literal. `0` is a number. You should also **not** store dates in `text` columns.

Comment: Dates and '0' are here because of internationalization issues and VB.NET issues. Those '0' is for double precision numbers stored that way. OK, not proper but I use that in many tables. Here is something specific.

Comment: The `'0'` is the root of your problem. It is not a number. You have to use `0` for a number value.

Comment: `''` is not a double precision number either.  If you mean NULL, use NULL.

Comment: Find an error!! In creating table "pdobid int, " is attempt to be written like string pdoboib=''. And actually it is a string. My syntax error, sorry. "Name", I get from those systems what is possible at possible way. With C or C++ is much easier to work with PostgreSQL. Anyway, even with them I never sucessfuly writes a double number to PG table like 1254,3215 like is usual in my country. In C/C++ I have to change my locale before update and return it back after it.

Comment: As an aside, isn't there something that uses placeholders and bound values in VB.net? There must be a better approach than all this string concatenation. And you should be dealing with L10N and I18N issues at the edges of the application: standardize on input, localize on output.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I added an answer concerning `'0'`, since it wouldn't fit into a comment.

Comment: "too short" here are some way to use PostrgrSQL with parameterized way of work, npgsql and some more but no one is simple like from C. However, I use PG that way and I am very satisfied with possibility to use such great database from VB.NET. With help of great community on this sites and good people now I can get dates and times written as above in regular PG 'timestamp', use 'ANY' with array written to string and other "nice" tricks. As you can see I don't even use try/catch blocks because errors are very rare and code fixing is for me better solution than hiding an errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advice to read the chapter [**Constants** in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS). It's a brief and informative read.
The cause for the error message is that `''` is an **empty string** that has no representation in a numeric type like `integer`.

@a_horse_with_no_name: To be precise, `'0'` is a *string* constant to PostgreSQL that can be cast to `integer` just as well as it can be cast to `text`, only `text` is the default for string constants. Consider this demo:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t (i int);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('2');        -- single row inserts to make sure ..
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('3'::int);   -- .. type is not coerced to type
INSERT INTO t VALUES (4::bigint);  -- .. of first row by VALUES expression.
INSERT INTO t VALUES (5::numeric);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (6);

UPDATE t SET i = '0' WHERE i = '6';
SELECT * FROM t;
```

[SQL Fiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/2ce7f/1)

Comment: The SQL standard calls `'foobar'` a *character string literal* :) I tend to avoid the name "string" in combination with SQL as it is not a regular datatype. And I strongly advice against using implicit datatype converstion. That is simply calling for trouble. Better to always use the proper literal (constant) syntax.

Comment: I'm actually surprised that `i = '0'` works. I thought those implicit casts had been removed with 8.3

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I think what has been removed with 8.3 is automatic coercion of a *numeric constant* to a character type. (`0` -> `'0'::text`). But a generic string constant (`'0'`) can be coerced to *any* type.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I think "string" is just the right term for a *string constant* like `'0'`, *because* "string" is not a regular data type - since the literal has not been cast to any data type yet.

Comment: OK, I see. But I still think it's bad practise to use the wrong literal "type" and rely on implicit data type conversion.

Comment: Thank you Ervin for a "brief casting course". Yes, I all time use doubles as strings and back with PostgreSQL where '0' is often input. I noted that PG won't take decimal coma which forces my locale on windows and linux too. Changing locale often on the fly don't seem's lucky solution anyway.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Well, I agree. If you can be more specific, you *should*  be. But it's helpful at times to have string constants (literals) that can be cast to *any* type.

Comment: @user973238: You can use the function [**`to_number()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) to convert a string to a `numeric` type, independent of locale.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks. So I can save much of my "replace work" :)