# SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: ""

Tags: php, postgresql

i'm trying to insert data in my db but i have this error and i don't understand by what it's caused so i need your help please to fix it

```
try{
$fileName = $_FILES['fichier']['name'];
$files = '../save_Data/'.$fileName;
$csv = new SplFileObject($files); // On instancie l'objet SplFileObject

$csv->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV); // On indique que le fichier est de type CSV
$csv->setCsvControl(','); // On indique le caractère délimiteur, ici c'est la virgule

/**
* Préparation de la requête avec les paramètres.
*/
$nox = 'INSERT INTO public.nox_donnees_brutes (nox_date, nox_no_ppb, nox_no2_ppb, nox_nox_ppb) VALUES(:nox_date, :nox_no_ppb, :nox_no2_ppb, :nox_nox_ppb)';
$stm = $this->db->prepare($nox);
$stm->bindParam('nox_date', $nox_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stm->bindParam('nox_no_ppb', $nox_no_ppb, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stm->bindParam('nox_no2_ppb', $nox_no2_ppb, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stm->bindParam('nox_nox_ppb', $nox_nox_ppb, PDO::PARAM_INT);

foreach ($csv as $line){
    $character_sets = array("ISO-10646", "ISO-8859-1", "ISO-8859-2", "ISO-8859-3", "ISO-8859-4", "ISO-8859-5", "ISO-8859-9", "ISO-8859-10",
                    "ISO-8859-13", "ISO-8859-14", "ISO-8859-15", "ISO-8859-16", "PC1250", "PC1251", "PC1252", "PC1253", "PC1254", "PC1255", "PC1256", "PC1257",
                    "PC1258", "Windows-1252", "UTF-8", "UTF-16", "UTF-32", "ASCII", "TOA5", "TOB1", "UTF-EBCDIC", "CESU-8", "BOCU-1");
    $convert_files = mb_convert_encoding($line, 'UTF-8', $character_sets);
    $nox_date = $convert_files[0];
    $nox_no_ppb = $convert_files[1];
    $nox_no2_ppb =  $convert_files[2];
    $nox_nox_ppb =  $convert_files[3];
    $stm->execute();
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    die('Erreur lors de l\'insertion des données : Error ['. $e->getCode().'] ' . $e->getMessage() .'</p>');
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR \[22P02\] ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "";](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201826/error-22p02-error-invalid-input-syntax-for-integer)

Answer (score 0):

Check your bind variables for empty / integer 
*testsetup:*

```
   $strQuery        = "INSERT INTO public.tbl_test (test) VALUES (:PNVALUE)";
   try {
        $stm = $con->prepare($strQuery);
        $stm->bindValue(':PNVALUE', $lsTest, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stm->execute();
        $arrResult    = $loStatement->fetchAll();
    } 
    catch(Exception $e) {
            // do something
    }
```

with :

```
$lsTest         = '1';  //ok
$lsTest         = 1;    //ok
$lsTest         = null; //ok
unset($lsTest);         // 'PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: lsTest in ...
$lsTest         = "";   // <- your error   invalid input syntax for integer: “”
```

so check your variables maybe this way :

```
 if(!is_int($lsTest)) {
     $lsTest = NULL;
 }
```

edit:

your code should look something like that:

```
foreach ($csv as $line){
    $character_sets = array("ISO-10646", "ISO-8859-1", "ISO-8859-2", "ISO-8859-3", "ISO-8859-4", "ISO-8859-5", "ISO-8859-9", "ISO-8859-10",
                    "ISO-8859-13", "ISO-8859-14", "ISO-8859-15", "ISO-8859-16", "PC1250", "PC1251", "PC1252", "PC1253", "PC1254", "PC1255", "PC1256", "PC1257",
                    "PC1258", "Windows-1252", "UTF-8", "UTF-16", "UTF-32", "ASCII", "TOA5", "TOB1", "UTF-EBCDIC", "CESU-8", "BOCU-1");
    $convert_files = mb_convert_encoding($line, 'UTF-8', $character_sets);
    $nox_date = $convert_files[0];

    $nox_no_ppb = $convert_files[1];
if(!is_int($nox_no_ppb )) {
   $nox_no_ppb = NULL;
}
$nox_no2_ppb =  $convert_files[2];
if(!is_int($nox_no2_ppb )) {
   $nox_no2_ppb = NULL;
}
$nox_nox_ppb =  $convert_files[3];
if(!is_int($nox_nox_ppb )) {
   $nox_nox_ppb = NULL;
}
$nox = 'INSERT INTO public.nox_donnees_brutes (nox_date, nox_no_ppb, nox_no2_ppb, nox_nox_ppb) VALUES(:nox_date, :nox_no_ppb, :nox_no2_ppb, :nox_nox_ppb)';

$stm = $this->db->prepare($nox);
$stm->bindParam('nox_date', $nox_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stm->bindParam('nox_no_ppb', $nox_no_ppb, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stm->bindParam('nox_no2_ppb', $nox_no2_ppb, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stm->bindParam('nox_nox_ppb', $nox_nox_ppb, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$stm->execute();
}
```

Comment: So i check like your exemple and i haven't errors but i don't have insertion in my table. what i should make ?

Comment: can you update/ edit your question with the code you use now, please ?

Comment: @Barys the correct way is first do set the value of variables then prepare and bind and execute the query, changing the values afterwards and executing again, well it wount throw errors, but executes the last prepared statement (without the valuechange), but does not do, what you want

Comment: if (!is_null($nox_date) && !is_int($nox_no_ppb) && !is_int($nox_no2_ppb) && !is_int($nox_nox_ppb)) {
     $nox_date =   $convert_files[0];
     $nox_no_ppb  =   $convert_files[1];
     $nox_no2_ppb =   $convert_files[2];
     $nox_nox_ppb =   $convert_files[3];
     $stm->execute(); 
    }                                                                                                                            I dot that.